# Start an activity using a 3d flip animation

Tags: android, layout, animation, android-activity

I'm trying to start an activity and create the transition as a 3d flip (as many have stated exactly like on the IPhone), unfortunately I haven't found a satisfying answer yet and I am stuck.

I've implemented http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/08/android-animations-3d-flip.html
for the whole layout so that now when pressing a certain button the layouts are flipped, but since it refers to layout that are in activities which weren't loaded, they don't fill all their items and data (an expandable list view for example).

But when i call startActivity() after the flip the activity is created which of course hides the framelayout container on the caller activity - so i can't flip back... (I've used the overridePendingTransition but imho it shouldn't matter).

I could really use your help am losing my mind...
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry you can't do this -- the window manager currently only supports 2d animations.

Comment: If Developer use Android 2.2 or above then also 3d animation is not supported ?

Comment: 3d window animations are still not supported as of 4.0.

Comment: While 3D window animations are not supported, you can create an Activity, call setContentView(), and in onAttachedToWindow() (API 7 or higher) you can run a Flip3dAnimation on your View to achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

I also want to flip activity as 3D animation. I just found this solution http://blog.robert-heim.de/karriere/android-startactivity-rotate-3d-animation-activityswitcher/

What they does.. startActivity with no animation any apply 3D rotation on it.